# Make laravel mix proxy address the same for all projects

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack

I have some laravel mix settings for my project:

```
  mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/scss/main.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/scss/test.scss', 'public/css')
   .options({
      processCssUrls: false
   })

  .copyDirectory('resources/images', 'public/images')
  .copyDirectory('resources/fonts', 'public/fonts')
  .browserSync({
    proxy: 'quiz.local',
    files: ["public/css/main.css", "public/js/*.js"],
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    }
})
```

What I don't like about these settings is that the proxy address is not good - if another developer has a different local address, it's not gonna work for them. Is there any way to make it useful for all the developers apart from asking them to change the local server name to quiz.local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject [environment variables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix#environment-variables) into mix. In theory, each `.env` file should be unique / not uploaded to version control anyway.

> **You may inject environment variables into Mix** by prefixing a key in
>   your .env file with MIX_:
>
> `MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC=http://example.com`
>
> After the variable has been
>   defined in your .env file, you may access via the process.env object.
>   If the value changes while you are running a watch task, you will need
>   to restart the task:

Following this, your mix file would end up looking something like this;

```
.browserSync({
    proxy: process.env.MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC,
    files: ["public/css/main.css", "public/js/*.js"],
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    }
```

Comment: hi, thank you very much for your response, but could you please elaborate on that a little?

I should create a variable MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC in my .env file and set it to my local address - that's what I've got so far; what should I do next? What does "you may access via the process.env object" mean?

Comment: change the proxy to `proxy: process.env.MIX_SENTRY_DSN_PUBLIC,` is probably what is meant here and then ask the other developers to fill in their .env files accordingly

Comment: @apokryfos got it, thanks! Now it works, but I don't really understand how it is going to work if smb's local address will not be equal to quiz.local; is it really going to work for them?

Sorry if it's a silly question, just trying to understand the idea

Comment: @MikeL. Each developer will add this entry to their `.env` file, specifying their own local domain.